# Load External Handlebars Template for Postman Visualize

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, postman

Hot to load external handlebars templates (eg. loaded from HTTP server) to Postman Visualizer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load external templates put the following code in your script:

```
pm.sendRequest('https://your-server.net/postman/external-template.handlebars',  (_, res) => ( temp = res.text()));
setTimeout(() => pm.visualizer.set(temp, {res: pm.response.json()}),250)
```

Change the URL and the timeout milliseconds value (how slow is your server to respond?) accordingly.